# I'm getting “DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable type” How do I fix it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am getting a

> DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types

error on the following LINQ to Entity query:

[image]

Comment: What is the **type** of the `Id` property?

Comment: Is `x.Id` a `string`?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it.. Problem was x.Id is Guid type..

```
        ModelContainer _dataContext = new ModelContainer();
        Guid gId= Guid.Parse(ArtistID);
        var artists = _dataContext.Artists.Select(x => new
        {
            x.FirstName,
            x.LastName,
            x.Id,
            x.Country,
            x.City,
            x.artSpecialty,
            x.approval_status,
            x.ProfilePic,
            x.Nationality,
            x.Website,
            x.Instagram,
            x.FaceBook,
            x.Twitter
        }).Where(x => x.Id.Equals(gId)).FirstOrDefault();
```